# category_ids to category in magento

Tags: mysql, magento

I am exporting products in magento 1.3 to magento 1.6, in magento 1.3's .csv it has a field category_ids and in magento 1.6's .csv has _category field. I just want to have same .csv attribute field of magento 1.3 the same with .csv magento 1.6 so that I can import the .csv in magento 1.3 to magento 1.6.

My problem now is that how can I query in my mysql to get the category name from category_ids in magento 1.3 ?

I look in the tables in magento 1.3 but there is no category name in there.

In the .csv of magento 1.3 it has this table

```
category_ids
------------
154
154
154
59
63,88
63
61
```

i try this sql query but nothing return..

```
SELECT catalog_category_entity_varchar.value FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE value_id = 154;
```

Do anyone have an idea about my case? thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get now the query  and this is it ...

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id = 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

For getting all the Categories use the Following Query:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar where attribute_id=111;
```

you will get the following values value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value.

Here, entity_id - CategoryID, Value is Category Name.

```
value_id     entity_type_id       attribute_id      store_id     entity_id      value
   1               9                111                 0            3       'Root Catalog'
   4               9                111                 0            4       'Shirts'
   7               9                111                 0            5       'Shoes'
```

if you want to get the Category Name by specific, then you use the following query:

```
SELECT catalog_category_entity_varchar.value FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar where attribute_id=111 and entity_id=4;
```

4- CategoryId